# Azure ChatBot Built in Python Cannot handle HTTPS

Tags: python, azure, chatbot

[image]

The chatbot runs fine and accepts requests that are targeting http but fails to handle https

[image]

I am running a simple test bot
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/05.multi-turn-prompt

The Azure ChatBot only allows https urls, however the same code provided by Microsoft doesn't work for this. Is there a way to modify the python to also handle HTTPS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by modifying the default code in the main (also make sure to import ssl)

```
import ssl
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
        ssl_context.load_cert_chain('./certs/cert.pem', './certs/key.pem')
        web.run_app(APP, host="localhost", port=CONFIG.PORT, ssl_context=ssl_context)
    except Exception as error:
        raise error
```

Keep in mind you cannot use self-signed certs, even for testing

[image]